# How to trigger an AWS Lambda function that takes input from a Flutter screen

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, dart, aws-lambda

I'm building mobile app, upon refresh (clicking refresh button or pull down) i need to call AWS lambda and display latest data. Tried couple of options but could not succeed. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application should call API Gateway (with cognito), and it trigger your lambda.

Answer (score 1):

You can create FunctionUrl for your lambda and then make an HTTP Request from your mobile app.

Steps to create FunctionUrl:

1. Head to your lambda page on AWS Console
2. Click on Configuration tab
3. From the side-panel, choose Function Url
4. Click "Create Function Url"
5. Choose the appropriate Auth type, either NONE (anyone can call your function Url) or AWS_IAM (authenticated users or Roles can call the function)
6. Click Save

Finally you can copy the function URL and make the request from your mobile app.